# Django namespacing still produces collision

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have two apps using same names in my django project. After configuring namespacing, I still get collision. For example when I visit `localhost:8000/nt/`, I get template from the other app. (localhost:8000/se/ points to the right template).

I must have missed something. Here is the code:

*dj_config/urls.py*

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("se/", include("simplevent.urls", namespace="se")),
    path("nt/", include("nexttrain.urls", namespace="nt")),
    # ...
]
```

*dj_apps/simplevent/urls.py*

```py
from . import views

app_name = "simplevent"

urlpatterns = [
    path(route="", view=views.Landing.as_view(), name="landing")
]
```

*dj_apps/nexttrain/urls.py*

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "nexttrain"

urlpatterns = [
    path(route="", view=views.Landing.as_view(), name="landing"),
]
```

*dj_config/settings.py*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "dj_apps.simplevent.apps.SimpleventConfig",
    "dj_apps.nexttrain.apps.NexttrainConfig",
    # ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ....
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True, 
    }
```

Both views will have the same code:

```py
class Landing(TemplateView):
    template_name = "landing.html"
```

Templates are located in:

- dj_apps/simplevent/templates/landing.html
- dj_apps/nexttrain/templates/landing.html

Note that reversing order of apps in INSTALLED_APPS will reverse the problem (`/se` will point to nexttrain app).

Comment: Shouldn't this in the view code be `template_name = "simplevent/landing.html"` and similarly for the other app?

Comment: @vinkomlacic not with APP_DIRS=True. Doing so will create a `TemplateDoesNotExist ` error. Your solution would work with APP_DIRS=False and moving templates outside of apps. But I'd like to avoid this architecture as it makes no sense in my case.

Comment: Ahh okay. I think that there is an error with the template paths. It should be: `dj_apps/simplevent/templates/simplevent/landing.html` and the `template_name` as proposed in the first comment. I think this should solve your problem of confused templates.

Comment: @vinkomlacic It would indeed solve the issue but 1- I don't understand the whole point of using APP_DIRS=True if we need to reencapsulate with the app name. 2- Then I got the same issue with static files (it uses the wrong output.css file).

I have the feeling I did not find the right way to have a strong split between my apps :/

Comment: It think it's the correct way to do it. Django does it like this because when `collectstatic` is run, it practically copies the files from `templates` folder of each app and places it in one static folder. This is why the app name needs to be twice in the path. Because in the final folder you end up with the app names already there. Also, you could have in your app overridden templates from third party apps (e.g. admin). It sounds a bit too convoluted for me too, but I'm pretty sure that is the intended way you're supposed to separate templates.

Comment: BTW, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates), the template backend only looks in the app folders if you specify `APP_DIRS=True`, so that is its purpose. Otherwise, it only looks in the folders specified in `DIRS`.

Comment: @vinkomlacic makes sense, you must be right. Thanks for the explanation. And does this mean I need to do the same with all my `static` folders? i.e. instead of having `myapp/static/xxx` should I have `myapp/static/myapp/xxx`?

Comment: @vinkomlacic Thanks again, it works as expected, even if it's a little more verbose now :) Do you want to write an answer to be accepted? Otherwise I'll write it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual structure that your template backend expects when looking for template files is: `<your app>/templates/<your app>/some_template.html`, so your template paths should be:

- `dj_apps/simplevent/templates/simplevent/landing.html`
- `dj_apps/nexttrain/templates/nexttrain/landing.html`

Django does it like this because when `collectstatic` is run, it practically copies the files from templates folder of each app and places it in one static folder. This is why the app name needs to be twice in the path. Because in the final folder you end up with the app names already there. Also, you could have in your app overridden templates from third party apps (e.g. admin). It sounds a bit too convoluted for me too, but I'm pretty sure that is the intended way you're supposed to separate templates.

Also, in your view, you need to have the app name when specifying the `template_name` option:

```py
# simplevent app
class Landing(TemplateView):
    template_name = "simplevent/landing.html"


# nexttrain app
class Landing(TemplateView):
    template_name = "nexttrain/landing.html"
```

PS. the same principle is applied to static folders.